# How to fix a git log author name?

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

When my development team uses git to commit, there times where they do it from an environment they are new in. When this happens, their git config has not been properly set up and they commit to the codebase with a default "root@localhost.localdomain" author name. This is very annoying in terms of the git log. We can eliminate this via processes, but human error is unavoidable at times.

Is there a way to change those incorrect author names or have a way to enforce correct author names before commit? For example, I can set up a list of authorized authors and anyone not using the author name cannot commit.

Comment: Read about [Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). You might even find ones that do what you want already.

Comment: And you can also use [git filter-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) to change the authors of the commits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with rewriting the git history like that is that once you change one commit, all commits that depend on it also change. In other words, if you want to preserve all commit IDs after the one you are trying to change, you cannot change the commit you want to change.

If you are OK with messing up IDs of the commits following the one you are changing, you can use a recipe like this to alter the details of the commit:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
if [ $GIT_COMMIT = %COMMITID% ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss z"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss z"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Name"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="email@address"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Name"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="email@address"
fi
' -- %COMMITID%~..HEAD
```

Where `%COMMITID% is replaced with the ID of the commit you want to change. Example:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 1234567890ABCD ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Name"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="email@address"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Name"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="email@address"
fi
' -- 1234567890ABCD~..HEAD
```

Warning! Again, you are changing not only that commit but every single one that sits on top of it.

- Because of the above you will have now "evil twin" "ghost" "old" commit tree still hang around. You can clean up with:

  git filter-branch -f --env-filter "" -- %COMMITID%~..HEAD
- You will have to overwrite remote branch with new commits, as simply pushing it will not work - remote server will complain. Either "force" it, or delete remote branch before you push that rewritten branch up:

  git push remote_address_or_name :branch_name

Example:

```
git push origin :feature_a
```

- You will have to make all other team members rebase on top of the new tree. And they will likely have to do something like `git fetch --all -p` to cleanse their local history of the rewritten remote branch before they can rebase on top of it.

Based on the above, you better look at some **server-side** `pre-receive` hooks that stop `push` that contains offending commits and inform the team members how to use the above-mentioned `filter-branch` magic to rid their commits of offending messages.